# Disallow header page robots.txt

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

I want to disallow header.php in robots.txt from being indexed.
File url:

```
https://example.com/header.php
```

But I'm not sure what is correct:

```
Disallow: /header.php
```

or

```
Disallow: header.php
```

Comment: Questions of this nature are better suited to the Webmasters Stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL-paths specified in `robots.txt` should always start with a slash (ie. root-relative).

From [Google's robots.txt specification](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt#group-member-rules):

> The [path] value, if specified, is to be seen relative from the root of the website for which the robots.txt file was fetched (using the same protocol, port number, host and domain names). **The path value must start with "/" to designate the root.** The path is case-sensitive.

So, you should write:

```
Disallow: /header.php
```

However, this prevents *crawling*, it does not necessarily prevent *indexing* if this URL is being linked to. Although, I suspect this is just an HTML-fragment(?), so blocking crawling would be the thing to do in this situation. (But note that if you have many *includes* then they are better contained in a subdirectory and simply block the subdirectory.)

Test your `robots.txt` file in [Google's robots.txt tester](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en) before going live.